# Java I/O issue when dealing with files

Tags: java, file, io

I'm currently learning Java I/O , when I compile this code :

```
    import java.io.File;   
    public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){
            //Creation of the File object
            File f = new File("test.txt");
            System.out.println("File absolute path : " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("File name : " + f.getName());
            System.out.println("Does it exist ? " + f.exists());
            System.out.println("Is it a directory? " + f.isDirectory());
            System.out.println("Is it a file ? " + f.isFile());
}
```

The problem is `f.exists()`  and `f.isFile()`return `false`

How is that even possible ?

Comment: First line of the javadoc : "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames."

Comment: keep the file right inside the project folder , parallel to src folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with the program except the file location
there are two solutions

1 : you can store the file in the project directory , parallel to src folder

2 you can create the file with full path specified

```
File f = new File("D:/folder1/folder2/applicationname/src/test.txt");
```

Comment: no no no , i am just taking the reference for already existing file

Comment: OK but the OP didn't say in his post that the actual file already existed, hence you assumed that it existed and posted the answer . Right ?

Comment: This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 9):

```
    File f = new File("test.txt");
```

The above line doesn't create an physical file on the disk. it only creates a file object, with the name 'test.txt', thus File#exits() returns false.

You need to create an actual physical file in number of ways.

**Using File**

```
file.createNewFile()
```

**using FileWriter**

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);
```

PS: same applies for File#isFile() returning false as well.

Comment: I didn't understand well , how to create a real file on the disk ?

Comment: @Kafil10: Did you see the word `createNewFile`?

Comment: File#createNewFile() creates a new physical file on the disk. you can also use Writers to create a physical file by passing the file object as a arguments to their constructor. i would recommend you to have a glance at File API and also oracle tutorial on File IO . :)

Comment: @Kafil10 look over here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html.

Comment: I got it ( Finally ) Thanks for you help all of you

Answer (score 5):

`File` is not a file—it is just a *descriptor* of a native filesystem resource that may or may not exist. For example, you can do `new File(path).createNewFile()`.

Answer (score 2):

`new File("test.txt")` It creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname not physical file.

you can call `File#createNewFile()`. It atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.

Comment: Why do you guys us # instead of . operator , you got me all confused for a while

Comment: `ClassX.method` means a *static* method of `ClassX` and `ClassX#method` means an *instance* method of `ClassX`. This notation was borrowed from the Ruby world. It is very practical.